# How are "[]" and "[...]" used in in-text reference

Tags: grammaticality, citation

I've seen direct quotations which use "[]" and "[...]", but so far I've been unable to find a definition for the syntax. Specifically, the text could be like:

> [S]o here we don't use the ellips.

> [...] but here we do.

I've inferred that "[]" is used to indicate that the cited letter should be a lower case, while "[...]" implies a partial citation. Is my assessment correct, and what is the name of the usage of "[]" and "[...]" in text?

Comment: Not everything has a category. [My very own special thought] inserts the writer's twist that is not in the original. [S] means the original did not have "S," probably lowercase as you guessed, but not necessarily. It is not a *should be* on the original, but honoring it.

Comment: Does this answer your first question [Changing case within quoted text](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132290/changing-case-within-quoted-text) and this your second [Fragmented Quotes and Bracketed Ellipses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153290/fragmented-quotes-and-bracketed-ellipses)?